# tar: Removing leading `../' from member names

Tags: tar

I am testing out the functionality of tar by compressing and extracting directories as follows:

```
cd test
mkdir Documents
mkdir foo
cd foo  
sudo tar cf - ../Documents | tar xf -
```

The last command gives me the following error:

```
tar: Removing leading `../' from member names
```

I know that we need to force tar to take in absolute pathnames but this is a relative one. Why isn't tar accepting this argument?

Comment: See [tar: Removing leading \`/' from member names](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59243)

Answer (score 2):

From `tar` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tar.1.html):

> ```
> -P, --absolute-names
>       don't strip leading '/'s from file names
> ```

You should run:

```
sudo tar cPf - ../Documents | tar xPf -
```